# Why is maven so slow

Tags: maven, networking, build

So this is my frustration with Maven. It takes ages to get dependencies if you are starting afresh. Given that it knows we need x number of dependencies, why can't it get all of them in parallel? Is there any design decision behind doing it serially that I am missing?

Comment: How long does it really take? How many modules? How many tests are you running and how long do the tests take? Are you using a repository manager which caches everything from Central...? Do you have real measured times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven is only serially building by default, you can also switch to parallel builds with, e.g.:

```
mvn -T 4 clean install
```

That would cause maven to use four threads while building, for further documentation have a look at [Parallel builds in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Fabian